# strange message sh:line 1 trace xcode-select when running a ruby program

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, sequel

So I ran into problems installing "mysql" and "sequel" for connecting to my localhost on my mac with Ruby.  I fixed the issue by changing an environment variable on my mac but here was the original error.

```
> sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/path/to/mysql_config
> sudo gem install sequel
> ruby db-connect.rb
> /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': LoadError: dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/mysql-2.9.1/mysql/mysql_api.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (Sequel::AdapterNotFound)
Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/mysql-2.9.1/mysql/mysql_api.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/mysql-2.9.1/mysql/mysql_api.bundle
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

So I started snooping around and I found a tidbit of code to put in my ~/.profile file

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

And tada!  It works.  But if I fire up the terminal with this line uncommented in my bash profile, it spits out this line every time I run a ruby program:

```
> irb
sh: line 1: 16604 Trace/BPT trap: 5       xcode-select --print-path > /dev/null 2>&1
irb(main):001:0>
```

I am able to connect to the database and get information but I don't like that message.  If I comment out the export line in my file and turn on a new terminal, the message disappears but then I am no longer able to connect to mysql and get the same AdapterNotFound for libmysqlclient.18.dylib

What's causing this message?  How can I get rid of it or suppress it?  Maybe there's a better way of doing this?

MacOSX Yosemite, latest XCode, ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14], ruby on rails

EDIT

gem env

RubyGems Environment:

```
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.2
- RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-05-08 patchlevel 481) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/paulcarlton/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
- ruby
- universal-darwin-14
- GEM PATHS:
 - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
 - /Users/paulcarlton/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
 - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
 - :update_sources => true
 - :verbose => true
 - :backtrace => false
 - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
 - https://rubygems.org/
- SHELL PATH:
 - /opt/local/bin
 - /opt/local/sbin
 - /usr/local/share/npm/bin
 - /opt/local/php5/bin
 - /opt/local/bin
 - /opt/local/sbin
 - /usr/local/bin
 - /usr/bin
 - /bin
 - /usr/sbin
 - /sbin
 - /usr/local/git/bin
 - /usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
 - /usr/texbin
 - /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools
```

Which ruby:

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Comment: Based on what you say you did, and the output messages you got, I think you haven't told us everything. Did you use `sudo` to install MySQL and Sequel? Or do you have rbenv or RVM installed and Ruby is in a sandbox? Please add the output of `gem env` and `which ruby` to your question.

Comment: @theTinMan - Well, I don't think "sandbox" is the case but I'm not sure.  I'm using the version of Ruby that comes installed on the mac.  Yes I used `sudo` while executing those commands.  That is now updated in the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. STOP modifying the Apple-supplied Ruby unless you are absolutely sure of what you're doing. It was put there for Apple's use. We can piggy back on that, but don't change it, which would happen using `sudo gem...`.
2. Use either [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) to install and manage separate Rubies for you. If you go with RVM, read its installation page so you understand what it will do; It's powerful and with power comes more complexity. If you don't need that power, start with rbenv and switch if you ever find it isn't capable. I use them both, but on separate machines, as they are not compatible.
3. If using either rbenv or RVM, do NOT use `sudo` at all if working with Rubies or gems managed by either app. `sudo` temporarily raises your privileges to those of root, which won't know about your local Ruby installation, and again will install over Apple's Ruby.

---

I keep this bash script on my machine to make it easier to get the MySQL gem installed:

```
#!/bin/sh -x

MYSQL_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin
LOCAL_MYSQL_LIB=/usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
MYSQL_LIB=/usr/lib/`basename $LOCAL_MYSQL_LIB`

[ -f $LOCAL_MYSQL_LIB ] || echo "Can't find $LOCAL_MYSQL_LIB" && exit
[ -f $MYSQL_LIB ]       || echo "Linking $MYSQL_LIB to $LOCAL_MYSQL_LIB" && sudo ln -s $LOCAL_MYSQL_LIB $MYSQL_LIB

PATH=$PATH:$MYSQL_PATH
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=$MYSQL_PATH/mysql_config
```

You can modify that for your own use.

Comment: This worked.  After installing using rvm using new version of ruby and installing rails, sequel and mysql on that, I'm able to connect with no issues.  Thanks!